# Does the Scrapy CloseSpider exception still redirect to a user-defined pipeline shutdown procedure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, pipeline

After I raise the Scrapy exception CloseSpider, I'd like a graceful shutdown with Scrapy executing my pipeline procedures before exiting.

Does it do this naturally? Or does it immediately terminate all scripts?

Comment: Any uncaught exception in Python (i.e. any exception outside a try block) results in immediate termination, you have to handle your error if you want to execute script after encountering an error.

Comment: Thanks Anand but CloseSpider is part of the Scrapy library

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Hi Gallaecio - I should have deleted my question. Because of the time it takes to shut down all the items queued - I thought the implementation was failing. It does go through all the normal close down processes, including finishing the pipeline procedures of the items already scraped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the time it takes to shut down all the items queued - I thought the implementation was failing. It does go through all the normal close down processes, including finishing the pipeline procedures of the items already scraped.